# Confusion with identities in different function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ be the space of vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Schwartz function components.

Next, let $\mathcal{S}_{div}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ be the space of divergence-free vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Schwartz function components.

Then, the well-known Helmholtz decomposition tells us that the mapping
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} : \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3) \to \mathcal{S}_{div}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)
\end{equation}
is a projection, which is in fact known as the Leray-Hopf projection.

Now, fix any $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ which has nonzero divergence, so that $f \neq \mathbb{P}f$ as functions.

However, with the notation
\begin{equation}
\langle f, g \rangle : =\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f \cdot g
\end{equation}
it is clear that
\begin{equation}
\langle f, g \rangle = \langle \mathbb{P} f, g \rangle 
\end{equation}
for all $g \in \mathcal{S}_{div}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$, so that
\begin{equation}
f = \mathbb{P} f \text{ as elements of the dual space of } \mathcal{S}_{div}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)
\end{equation}

Is my reasoning correct? So, $f$ and $\mathbb{P}f$ do not coincide functions BUT coincide as  continuous linear functionals on the space of divergence-free vector fields?

This looks quite subtle and confusing.. Could anyone pleae clarfiy?

Answer (score -1):

Let $V$ be an inner product space with a subspace $W$ and an orthogonal projection $\pi:V\to W.$

Then, for $\mathbf{v}\in V\setminus W$ one has $\pi\mathbf v\neq \mathbf v$ but still $\langle \pi \mathbf v, \mathbf u\rangle = \langle \mathbf v, \mathbf u\rangle$ for all $\mathbf u\in W$ since $\mathbf v - \pi\mathbf v$ is orthogonal to $W.$

This is exactly your situation with $V=\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3),$ $W=\mathcal{S}_{div}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $\pi=\mathbb P.$

Comment: Well, the Schwartz space is not an inner product space..

Comment: But you are not that wrong because we can replace the inner product by dual pairing anyway... so you agree with my conclusion of $f =\mathbb{P}f$ as linear functionals on the divergence-free subspace?

Comment: @Keith. Yeah, I was a little bit wrong there. I was about to go to bed so I was a bit in a hurry. Anyway, it shows that linear functionals can be different on the full space but be equal on a subspace. And that's the case in your situation.

Comment: @Keith. By the way, isn't $\langle f, g\rangle$ as you defined it an inner product on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$?

Comment: $<f, \cdot>$ above is a representation of the dual pairing with $f$ by means of the $L^2$ inner product. The  topology of Schwartz space itself cannot be described by the $L^2$ inner product alone, as is well-known.

Comment: @Keith. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) only defined an *inner product space* as a vector space equipped with an inner product; it isn't required that it has a topology given by the norm induced by the inner product.

Comment: well...that seems almost like calling $\mathbb{R}$ an abelian group to me.